# How to get fixed div to the bottom of other div?

Tags: html, css, scroll, popup, css-position

I am trying to build a digital restaurant menu… I designed it like a popup, so it sits in a fixed container on top of a gray transparent overlay. Since there are more dishes than fitting into this container, I wanted the container to be scrollable, which I achieved with `overflow-y: scroll`. **At this point** 
it still worked perfectly.

But on the bottom of the container I wanted fixed footer with a white-to-transparent gradient containing a button to close the whole menu popup. Since the stuff that I thought of didn't work, I placed it inside of another container on top of the popup… Now it looks as I wanted it, but the menu in the background is not scrollable anymore.

I guess there must be another way… How can I place the container with the close button on the bottom of the menu container while still being able to scroll?

[Here is a jsFiddle…](https://jsfiddle.net/hp970oLz/)

Comment: Can you make a more simple example instead of copy/pasting everything? Finding the correct divs etc. is quite a hassle now.

Comment: @Rvervuurt I made the fiddle a bit sleaker and commented the CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Your container for the button at the bottom is overlaying the scrollable container, so when you try and scroll the text, you're actually trying to scroll inside of the bottom-container as its over the top. I have made a JS fiddle, with an example of what you're trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ydb2h2m/

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}

    .box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 80%;
        max-height: 80%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 5% 10%;
        position: fixed;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .top-section {
        height: 20%;
        background: #c00;
    }

    .scroll-section {
        height: 70%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .bottom-section {
        height:  10%;
    }

    .button {
        background: #c00;
        height: 30px;
        width: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Ah! My bad, I can't really work out your code, but I have just put together an example of what it is you're trying to achieve. You can pull this one apart and use which parts you want =) https://jsfiddle.net/8ydb2h2m/

Comment: Ok, this time! haha... Set the bottom-section to absolute positioned, and set the background so it fades out the text > https://jsfiddle.net/8ydb2h2m/2/